# Three.js CameraHelper not working with Raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js

I cast ray on mouse click

```
    function onMouseClick(event){
        console.log(event);
        if(event.button == 0){
            const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, get_camera());
            const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.selectable, false );
            console.log("intersects=",intersects);
            if(intersects.length > 0){
                select_object(intersects[0].object.asset_name);
            } else {
                select_object(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the raycaster detects collision even though there shouldn't be any. Console log is as follows (25 collisions and all of them belonging to the same CamereHolder object)

[image]

when I click somewhere near the camera helper

[image]

Another time i tried clicking inside the CameraHelper but it doesn't get detected

[image]

It seems like the shape of CameraHelper is completely wrong. I tried inspecting `boundingBox` and `boundingSphere` but modifying them has no effect on Raycaster. Can anybody get Raycatser and CamerHelper to work properly or is it a bug in the library? If you can, could you please post a minimal code that works?

Comment: I think this is something in three.js . I ended up creating `ConeGeometry` and applying to it the camera matrix `camera_helper_cone.applyMatrix4(camera.matrix)` and then using the cone in `raycaster.intersectObjects`.

Comment: What is in `scene.selectable`?

Comment: a list of all meshes/objects in the scene, including CameraHelper, like the one you see in the JSON screenshot

Comment: I just noticed your `pointer` variable. Is that getting updated correctly? The raycaster needs to know its origin point. Also, if you're raycasting against moving objects, make sure you update their world matrices before doing the raycast. This will ensure they have the correct transformations applied so the raycaster than find them in the correct locations in 3D space.

Comment: @TheJim01 yes, the pointer is correct because it works fine for all other meshes and objects. And it also works well for the ConeGeometry that I added instead of CameraHelper.